# cannot see that device in android sdk target option (in eclipse)

Tags: android

I am new to android developed. however,

- got installed htc evo 4G drivers successfully (can see in device manager)

But

I cannot see that device in android sdk target option (in eclipse)

can someone help me in that please

regards

Comment: When you say "sdk target option" do you mean the "Project Build Target" in the project properties, or the android:targetSdkVersion attribute in the manifest, or something else? (BTW, if you put the "android" tag on your question then you might get a faster reponse.)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure u have enabled USB debugging on your phone Settings->Applications->Development->Usb debugging.
Connect your device

In Run configuration of project set Target selection mode as manual and run your project. You should get dialog where u will get choose your phone as option to run emulator.

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable USB debugging on your device by choosing Settings->Applications->Development->Usb debugging.
2. Connect your device with a USB cable
3. When debugging the app you should see a dialog the option to choose your device or an emulator.  If you don't see this then choose a different USB connection option on your device.  I chose "memory card access only" and that seems to work.